# MVC4 POST model from an action to another action skipping view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, http-post

I need to POST a register model from another model without showing the register model to the user in MVC 4. Please suggest.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean....

Comment: Actually, I need to let a user register through another approach. And what I am doing is, from an action, I have a register model ready for that user. And I need to send the model to POST Register action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your business logic out of the actions and into methods. Let your actions call those to do their work. Then instead of trying to abuse the framework to post data between actions, just call the method with the parameters you have.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is not the best approach, but you can put the model in hiddenfields

TempData example:

On redirecting Action:

```
TempData["model"] = model;
return RedirectToAction("DifferentAction");
```

On different Action

```
var myModel = (model)TempData["model"]
/* do register stuff */
```

Comment: Yes, but RedirectToAction is calling the Get action, not the Post one.

Answer (score 0):

I would store it in temp data and redirect instead of re-POSTing.

Comment: Redirecting is landing to the GET Register action, not the POST one.

Comment: @Sovan i would do that instead. POST involves a lot of work based on the client.